# Magnetometer sensor in android mobile to get directions

Tags: android, sensors, magnetometer

Here is code which is intended to make my Android mobile phone vibrate when some condition is true. It should vibrate till azimuth angle (which I get from magnetometer) is not in a given range.

But no matter in which direction I point the phone, it never vibrates. It enters the `if` statement but never the `while` statement. And the vibrate function is working (i.e. the phone isn't broken). My purpose is to find north south east west.

What am I doing wrong?

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // some code        
    mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
    if (mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD) != null){
        // Success! There's a magnetometer.
        Toast.makeText(
            getApplicationContext(),
            "Detecting magnetic field",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        speakOut("not Working");
    }
    else {
        Toast.makeText(
            getApplicationContext(),
            "not working",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        speakOut("not Working");
    }
    // some code that calls the function
}

some_function(){
    if (//some condition) {
        while (!(85 < azimuth_angle) && !(azimuth_angle < 95)) {
            viberator.vibrate(1000);
            //this should happen when it faces east.
        }
    } 
}

public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    // TODO: Auto-generated method stub
    azimuth_angle = event.values[0];
    pitch_angle = event.values[1];
    roll_angle = event.values[2];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`registerListener` method is missing so your `SensorEventListener` wont't be triggered: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager.html#registerListener(android.hardware.SensorEventListener, android.hardware.Sensor, int)

Answer (score 1):

Azimuth is not a compass direction.  Here's some code I wrote for a compass sensor.  It isn't 100% (it needs a much better filter on it, which I haven't had time or reason to write).  But it shows the logic of getting the direction, you can work on filtering the return values better yourself.

[Answer to previous question where I posted my code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14433182/direction-using-sensor/14433452#comment20094341_14433452)